# How to perform subtraction between DateTime in a Linq to Sql Select() method

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a linq query :

```
var NextWeekDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

var BirthData = db.EmployeeMasterAs
.Where(x => x.Emp_BirthDate >= CurrentDate)
.Select(x => new { x.Emp_BirthDate,
     DaysRemaining = (NextWeekDate - x.Emp_BirthDate).Value.TotalDays 
})
.OrderBy(x => x.Emp_BirthDate)
.ToList();
```

**Note** the element in `Select()` method, `DaysRemaining = (NextWeekDate - x.Emp_BirthDate).Value.TotalDays`, I want to get the difference between dates in days and save that to `DaysRemaining`, this query is not working and the exception that it throws :

> DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

I don't know exactly how to achieve this, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, Got it, So here is how it goes :

Performing arithmetic operations with Dates and Times is not supported in EF. EntityFramework cannot convert your code to SQL. Instead of that you can use `DbFunctions.DiffDays( startExpression, endExpression)` method:

```
db.EmployeeMasterAs
.Where(x => x.Emp_BirthDate >= CurrentDate)
.Select(x => new { x.Emp_BirthDate,
 DaysRemaining = DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.Emp_BirthDate,NextWeek)
})
.OrderBy(x => x.Emp_BirthDate)
.ToList();
```

**Furthermore** : `DbFunctions` Functions methods are called canonical functions. And these are a set of functions, which are supported by all Entity Framework providers. These canonical functions will be translated to the corresponding data source functionality for the provider. Canonical functions are the preferred way to access functionality outside the core language, because they keep the queries portable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that LinqToSql does not support DateTime.Subtract. But you can use the preexisting function SqlMethods.DateDiffDay (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468730(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit:** SqlMethods is only intended for SQL Server. DbFunctions is the helper class to pick regardless of the database type.